# Check if file exists, if not run FOR command (PowerShell / Batch)

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, for-loop

I'm looking to have a Batch (or PowerShell) file which goes through all Subfolders with a movie file, and runs Handbrake (application) on that movie file, then outputs a text file to that folder as a way of confirming the folder has been processed. That was fine for v1, but for v2 I need to check to see if that file exists… and that’s where I'm stuck.

The current FOR command is;

```
for /R .\ %%a in (*.avi,*.divx,*.m4v,*.mkv,*.mp4) do "%ProgramFiles%\Handbrake\HandBrakeCLI" --preset="iPod" --optimize --turbo --input="%%a" --output="E:\MobileMovies\%%~na.mp4"
```

Thanks in advance and hope that makes sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /R .\ %%a in (*.avi,*.divx,*.m4v,*.mkv,*.mp4
) do if not exist "%%~fa.processed" (
    "%ProgramFiles%\Handbrake\HandBrakeCLI" --preset="iPod" --optimize --turbo --input="%%a" --output="E:\MobileMovies\%%~na.mp4"
    break > "%%~fa.processed"
)
```

For each file in the set, if not exist a flag file `name.extension.processed` file in the same directory, then recode and generate the flag file

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `if [not] exist`, such as:

```
if not exist myfile.txt for /R .\ %%a in (*.avi,*.divx,*.m4v,*.mkv,*.mp4) do "%ProgramFiles%\Handbrake\HandBrakeCLI" --preset="iPod" --optimize --turbo --input="%%a" --output="E:\MobileMovies\%%~na.mp4"
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah that's what I was thinking but no matter how I have the if NOT exist it's just not working. Checked your above and that doesn't seem to work either